# VBA enable multiple selections from list box

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have created a listbox in Excel that is populated by a list from another sheet as below. I am wondering if there is a way to enable multiple selections from the list so I can then use the multiple selection to populate a new column and run some filters based on them.

```
Sub FilterUniqueData()
    Dim Lrow As Long, test As New Collection
    Dim Value As Variant, temp() As Variant
    ReDim temp(0)
    Dim Value1 As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    With Workbooks("Copy of SWR1304 (Future Development Risk Assessment) Strathaven.xls").Sheets("Non Household Metered Users")
        'Lrow = .Range("a" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    temp = .Range("h:h").Value
    End With


For Each Value In temp
    If Len(Value) > 0 Then test.Add Value, CStr(Value)
Next Value

    ReDim temp(0)
    Workbooks("DMA_metered_tool.xlsm").Worksheets("DMA list").Shapes("DMA_listbox").ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems

    For Each Value In test
         Worksheets("DMA list").Shapes("DMA_listbox").ControlFormat.AddItem Value
    Next Value

    Set test = Nothing

'Workbooks("DMA_metered_tool.xlsm").Worksheets("DMA list").Shapes("DMA_listbox").ControlFormat.List = Workbooks("Copy of SWR1304 (Future Development Risk Assessment) Strathaven.xls").Sheets("Non Household Metered Users").Range("h:h").Value
End Sub
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, the ListBox control has a MultiSelect property

Comment: As Jiminy mentions, there is a MultiSelect property. You can set this to `True` at Design time in the object's Properties window, or at runtime using `.MultiSelect = True`

Comment: If it's a Listbox, rather than Combobox, what is the "drop down list" to which you refer?

Comment: Good point @Rory, amended question to reflect this.

Comment: @Rory. Any idea how to get the selected items in the listbox to populate a column in another sheet? Cheers

Comment: Loop through the items using a counter and test if `.Selected(counter)` is true - if so, put `.List(counter, 0)` into the appropriate cell

Comment: @Rory that sounds good, don't have much experience of counters so any additional tips would be handy - no bother if not. Cheers.

Comment: Probably worth posting a new question giving details of the control and where you want the output - I'm sure someone will provide some code. :)

Comment: @Rory good plan, [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207699/vba-multiselect-listbox-populate-column-with-selected-items)

Answer (score 0):

Solution involves adding one line to the code after the box has been populated. Cheers for the input :)

```
Worksheets("DMA list").Shapes("DMA_listbox").ControlFormat.MultiSelect = xlSimple
```